# Docker CMD errors with File Not Found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I have built an image that has to run a python installation script start to finish, and is intended to function as an initContainer on k8s / Openshift.

The image builds fine, and when I locally do `docker run <image>` it starts up the script just fine. Also, when I (locally) inspect the file system of the container, the script is there, as expected.

However, when I run the same image as initContainer on Openshift, it keeps telling me "No such file or directory" when the script should be started.

- The docker file system has the script, it's just not found.
- I'm not mounting any volumes to the directory that holds the script, i.e. the directory should not be overwritten in any way.
- I have eliminated any issues around CRLF instead of LF (line endings) messing with the Shebang

I'm expecting this is due to the user's permissions, but I have no idea on how to fix it.

Dockerfile:

```
<do stuff, copy some scripts / perform some setup / install dependencies>

ARG USER_UID=1001
COPY myscript /opt/build/myscript
RUN chmod +x /opt/build/myscript &&\
    chown ${USER_UID}:0 -R /opt/build

CMD [ "/opt/build/myscript", "parameter1", "parameter2" ]
```

**TL;DR: How do I get the docker / user that it's running with to "see" this script and run it, on k8s?**

**Edit:** When I run the docker image as a k8s container instead of an initContainer, the script is found / this error isn't thrown.

**Edit 2:** Turned out to be a volume mount to a parent directory; answered my own question.

Comment: can you paste the error log directly?

Comment: Please include the exact commands run, the error message, a minimal script that will produce the error, and include debugging steps that show this is not a duplicate of similar questions.

Comment: There's only 1 log line in the output: `/bin/sh: /opt/build/myscript: No such file or directory` @LeiYang
@BMitch - The exact command is the CMD step above. I can't give the full contents of "myscript" (proprietary), but suffice to say "it doesn't even start, because it's not found".

Comment: Do you have some sort of volume mount over `/opt/build` that's hiding your script?  If you need to do an installation before the application can run, why not do it in the Dockerfile?

Comment: @DavidMaze I don't have volume mount over that dir, as put in the question. 
The "installation" in this case is compiling the output of a low code studio into something the final container can run. It shouldn't be done in the Dockerfile in this case, because we need to be able to dynamically load the "project to compile" into the deploymentConfig, so we don't replicate the entire docker build + release process for each project that's being started. The initContainers approach allows us to decouple these "low code projects" from the actual "runtime" release.

Comment: Edit: I'm dumb. There was a volume mount in the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initContainer had a volume mount that was overwriting a parent dir containing the script after all. I removed the volume mount and the script starts now.

Troubleshooting: Added command and args to the initContainer:

```
      initContainers:
        - name: build-project
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - '-c'
          args:
            - >-
              ls -la /path/to/script
```

and found it indeed didn't exist. There was a volume (`emptyDir: {}`) mounted to one of the parent directories.